# How to force hyperref to not touch one item, such as one footnote?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

How can I force `hyperref` to not touch one instance of something, for example one instance of a footnote. I looked at the manual of this package, for example [this link](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html) and [this one](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.dtx). You can open any of the two and search for `\hyper@nopatch@footnote` as an example. But the lack of example and demonstration, made me clueless that how to do this `\hyper@nopatch@footnote`. I tried type it in different locations of a TeX file, or to add it in some brackets in different locations, some newcommend definitions, but couldn't inverse engineer what it is supposed to mean.

If you want a piece of a tiny TeX example, then you can look at the following.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\footnotetext[1]{\label{foot:affiliation}Royal Persian Society of Science, Isfahan, Kingdom of Persia}

\setcounter{footnote}{1}

\author{
    AmirHosein Sadeghimanesh\footnoteref{foot:affiliation} \footnote{email-1@persia.ac.??}
    and
    My Collaborator\footnoteref{foot:affiliation} \footnote{email-2@persia.ac.??}
}

\title{How to have labels in footnotes in author section of a paper in \LaTeX without using a package}

\date{Mehr 28, 2581}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    Here we just write a sentence and give it a footnote to see that the index of footnotes are back to integers.\footnote{Just a footnote.}
    
\end{document}
```

Too read about this example see my other post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662420/22458. The goal is to force hyperref to not touch the affiliation footnote in the above file that is causing error message in this file. I tried some other suggestions at some other posts in this websites such as `\ref*` or `\@refstar` but no success. So I am more into knowing how to turn off `hyperref` on specific  places or items such as the footnote here.

---

Edit: As suggested by @UlrikeFischer, I put the `\maketitle` inside a `NoHyper` environment. Here is screenshot of what I get both in TeXStudio and VSCode's Latex Workshop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be duplicate of [Disable hyperref link for single footnote - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593640/disable-hyperref-link-for-single-footnote/593645#593645) but I didn't check

Comment: `\hyper@nopatch@footnote` allows to suppress all footnote patches made by hyperref and is meant for packages which want to support hyperlinking themselves, it is not meant for one footnote.

Comment: @user202729 no it is not duplicate of that question, I have seen that post, but couldn't use it to solve the issue with the footnote in the example above. What that post is doing is avoid using counter for the footnote. Here we are not trying to get rid of the counter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: use the NoHyper environment around \maketitle. (but I get no error from your example so I don't know what actually is your problem).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I still get the same error `Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }. \end`

Comment: show the complete log-file of your example above.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added.

Comment: that is not a log-file. It doesn't show the versions. Your example compiles with texlive 2021 and 2022 but breaks with older, so I guess you have an outdated tex system.

Comment: move the \footnotetext inside the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer here is a link to the log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4dCVNqUYR5HS_YOnkaNtWkVRwvzU9Uo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @UlrikeFischer moving the `\footnotetext` inside the document stopped the error message. Even without the `NoHyper` environment around maketitle. Thanks.